# Can I autodect a value in an angular directive instead of using a template reference variable?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

## What I got

I have a directive like this one:

```typescript
@Directive({
    selector: '[appValidateOnSubmit]'
})
export class ValidateOnSubmitDirective {

    @Input('appValidateOnSubmit')
    set appValidateOnSubmit(form: NgForm) {
        // do something with the form
    }
}
```

Usage:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" [appValidateOnSubmit]="myForm" #myForm="ngForm">
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

This so far works perfectly fine.

## Question

Can I somehow eliminate the template reference variable `myForm` from the HTML? So that I can write simply `<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" appValidateOnSubmit>` instead of the much longer `<form (ngSubmit)="submit()"[appValidateOnSubmit]="myForm" #myForm="ngForm">`?

<sub>Background is my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47735767/327301) which I am trying to improve.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do that using via `@Host`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appValidateOnSubmit]'
})
export class ValidateOnSubmitDirective {

  constructor(@Host() form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form);
  }
}
```