# Angular form error component trigger validation on form submit

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I'm using `Angular 8`.

I have the following reactive form group.

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
  query: ['', [
    Validators.required
  ]]
});
```

And in the HTML

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSubmit">
    <textarea formControlName="query" placeholder="SELECT ..."></textarea>
    <form-errors [control]="f.query"></form-errors>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The `form-errors` is a custom template which displays error message which has following method to trigger validation check on the control.

```js
shouldShowErrors(): boolean {
    return this.control && 
           this.control.errors && 
           (this.control.dirty || this.control.touched);
}
```

Thus validation is triggered when control is touched or changed.

**How can I trigger validation check on submit of the form? How can I access the `form` inside the `form-errors` component by the passed control?**

Answer (score 0):

You can [mark all controls as touched](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44150793/5621827) on submit button click like create a method for that and call it

```
 public markFormGroupTouched(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    Object.values(formGroup.controls).forEach(control => {
      control.markAsTouched();

      if (control.controls) {
          control.controls.forEach(c => this.markFormGroupTouched(c));
      }
    });
  }
  this.markFormGroupTouched(this.form);
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-eutrd2)

Comment: is `control.controls` for nested form group? Because it is giving error `AbstractControl has no attribute controls`. I solved it by making all `formGroup` touched by `formGroup.markAllAsTouched()` and its working.