# Template Driven Form Mark All as touched - Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, forms, validation, angular-material

I am using template driven forms for validations. And I would like to Mark all fields as touched when the user blur on the last required field. currently I am only able to do this by passing the form and individually doing each field. From research I see there is a way to do MarkAllAsTocuhed but it's throwing an error. Is there a better/correct way to do this with Angular 7. I also tried looping through the controls but since it's an object that also does not work.

.HTML

```
 <form #myForm="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field class="input-field">
              <input #field1="ngModel" name="name1" 
             [(ngModel)]="fieldOne" type="text" matInput placeholder="Field 1" required>     
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="input-field">
              <input #field2="ngModel" name="name2" 
             [(ngModel)]="fieldTwo" type="text" matInput placeholder="Field 2" required>     
    </mat-form-field> 

    <mat-form-field class="input-field">
              <input #field2="ngModel" name="name3" 
             [(ngModel)]="fieldThree" type="text" matInput placeholder="Field 3" required>     
    </mat-form-field> 

    <mat-form-field class="input-field">
              <input #field3="ngModel" name="name4" 
             [(ngModel)]="fieldFour" type="text" matInput placeholder="Field 4" 
             (blur)="touchAllFields(myForm.form)" required>     
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

.TS

```
touchAllFields(form){
//Working Version
form.controls.name1.markAsTouched();
form.controls.name2.markAsTouched();
form.controls.name3.markAsTouched();
form.controls.name4.markAsTouched();
form.controls.name5.markAsTouched();
form.controls.name6.markAsTouched();
form.controls.name7.markAsTouched();
form.controls.name8.markAsTouched();

//Failed Attempt
form.controls.markAllAsTouched(); //typeError: form.controls.markAllAsTouched is not a function

//Failed Attempt 
for(var i = 0; i < form.controls.length; i++){
  form.controls[i].markAllAsTouched(); //Failed since its an object and not an array
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Flash, you can check below urls for that. There have a solution it might be help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529817/reactive-forms-mark-fields-as-touched

Comment: Thanks that was actually my point of reference. But the solutions seemed to long an unnecessary. I would think I should be able to use markAllAsTouched somehow but thought I may be implementing it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

Found out that Object.keys can handle this.

```
 Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
      this.form.get(key).markAsTouched();
    });
```

For Angular 8+, you can use:

```
  Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
      this.form.controls[key].markAsTouched();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks the second one worked eventhough I'm using Angular 7. Any idea why do `form.controls.markAllAsTouched` does not work?

Comment: @Flash can you give me correct answer? I don't know, maybe the method doesn't exist!

Comment: yeah I got you in a couple of hours just wanna give others a chance to answer. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

#### `ngForm` itself has no `markAllAsTouched` method since it's not a `FormGroup` or `FormArray`. However, `NgForm` has an instance of a `formGroup` accessible via `.form` or `.control` - [source](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm).

> This has been available since Angular2 until the current latest version (Angular10)

So the correct answer to your questions should be as follows:

```
form.form.markAllAsTouched();
```

or

```
form.control.markAllAsTouched();
```